# Inductive Reasoning: Enumerative Induction question

Tags: logic

In enumerative inductions like the following, would the target group be "most Canadians" or would it just be all Canadians?

"Most Canadians agree that allowing the slaughter of dogs for food, although common in some countries, is unethical. A national newspaper recently surveyed 900 randomly selected pet owners. 94 per cent of respondents said that it is unethical to kill dogs to eat."

Answer (score 1):

One speaks about the **sample**, here the randomly selected pet owners, and the **population**, here all Canadian pet owners.  The enumerative induction concludes from the sample to the population.

In your example it would not be correct, to induce a statement about all Canadians or about most Canadians. Because the sample is taken from the proper subset of all Canadian pet owners. The sample is at most representative for Canadian pet owners, but not for **all** Canadians. It is also not representative for most Canadians, because the latter do not form a population.

The term **target group** belongs to a different context. It is the group of people addressed by a campaign. E.g. a company, which produces pet food, makes an advertisement about their product. Here the target group is the set of all pet owners in a certain region, possibly in all of Canada.

**Added** in reply to a comment: If the term "target group" is used in the context of
[enumerative induction](https://slideplayer.com/slide/15743569/), then it is a synonym of the target population, meaning the whole population under study, not the sample. In the pet-example the target group is the group of all Canadian pet owners.

Comment: Huh my textbook "The Power of Critical Thinking" - Chris MacDonald; Lewis Vaughn defines target group as "In enumerative induction, the whole collection of individuals under study", but is that not what it commonly means even in this context?

Comment: I expanded my answer.